# how do i plot time on x-axis in canvas js chart?

Tags: javascript, datetime, charts

i have a values in date time format. I want to show the time on x-axis instead of date.

> {"dateTime":"2016-03-16
>   07:09:41","value":"41.0"},{"dateTime":"2016-03-16
>   07:09:43","value":"43.0"},{"dateTime":"2016-03-16
>   07:09:45","value":"45.0"},{"dateTime":"2016-03-16
>   07:09:47","value":"47.0"},{"dateTime":"2016-03-16
>   07:09:49","value":"49.0"},{"dateTime":"2016-03-16
>   07:09:51","value":"51.0"},{"dateTime":"2016-03-16
>   07:09:53","value":"53.0"},{"dateTime":"2016-03-16
>   07:09:55","value":"55.0"},{"dateTime":"2016-03-16
>   07:09:57","value":"57.0"},{"dateTime":"2016-03-16
>   07:09:59","value":"59.0"},{"dateTime":"2016-03-16
>   07:10:01","value":"1.0"},{"dateTime":"2016-03-16
>   07:10:03","value":"3.0"},{"dateTime":"2016-03-16
>   07:10:05","value":"5.0"},{"dateTime":"2016-03-16
>   07:10:07","value":"7.0"},{"dateTime":"2016-03-16
>   07:10:09","value":"9.0"},{"dateTime":"2016-03-16
>   07:10:11","value":"11.0"},{"dateTime":"2016-03-16
>   07:10:13","value":"13.0"},{"dateTime":"2016-03-16
>   07:10:15","value":"15.0"},{"dateTime":"2016-03-16
>   07:10:17","value":"17.0"},{"dateTime":"2016-03-16
>   07:10:19","value":"19.0"},{"dateTime":"2016-03-16
>   07:10:21","value":"21.0"},{"dateTime":"2016-03-16
>   07:10:23","value":"23.0"},{"dateTime":"2016-03-16
>   07:10:25","value":"25.0"},{"dateTime":"2016-03-16
>   07:10:27","value":"27.0"},{"dateTime":"2016-03-16
>   07:10:29","value":"29.0"},{"dateTime":"2016-03-16
>   07:10:31","value":"31.0"},{"dateTime":"2016-03-16
>   07:10:33","value":"33.0"},{"dateTime":"2016-03-16
>   07:10:35","value":"35.0"},{"dateTime":"2016-03-16
>   07:10:37","value":"37.0"},{"dateTime":"2016-03-16
>   07:10:39","value":"39.0"},{"dateTime":"2016-03-16
>   07:10:41","value":"41.0"},{"dateTime":"2016-03-16
>   07:10:43","value":"43.0"},{"dateTime":"2016-03-16
>   07:10:45","value":"45.0"},{"dateTime":"2016-03-16
>   07:10:47","value":"47.0"},{"dateTime":"2016-03-16
>   07:10:49","value":"49.0"},{"dateTime":"2016-03-16
>   07:10:51","value":"51.0"},{"dateTime":"2016-03-16
>   07:10:53","value":"53.0"},{"dateTime":"2016-03-16
>   07:10:55","value":"55.0"},{"dateTime":"2016-03-16
>   07:10:57","value":"57.0"},{"dateTime":"2016-03-16
>   07:10:59","value":"59.0"},{"dateTime":"2016-03-16
>   07:11:01","value":"1.0"},{"dateTime":"2016-03-16
>   07:11:03","value":"3.0"},{"dateTime":"2016-03-16
>   07:11:05","value":"5.0"},{"dateTime":"2016-03-16
>   07:11:07","value":"7.0"},{"dateTime":"2016-03-16
>   07:11:09","value":"9.0"},{"dateTime":"2016-03-16
>   07:11:11","value":"11.0"},{"dateTime":"2016-03-16
>   07:11:13","value":"13.0"},{"dateTime":"2016-03-16
>   07:11:15","value":"15.0"},{"dateTime":"2016-03-16
>   07:11:17","value":"17.0"},{"dateTime":"2016-03-16
>   07:11:19","value":"19.0"},{"dateTime":"2016-03-16
>   07:11:21","value":"21.0"},{"dateTime":"2016-03-16
>   07:11:23","value":"23.0"},{"dateTime":"2016-03-16
>   07:11:25","value":"25.0"},{"dateTime":"2016-03-16
>   07:11:27","value":"27.0"},{"dateTime":"2016-03-16
>   07:11:29","value":"29.0"},{"dateTime":"2016-03-16
>   07:11:31","value":"31.0"},{"dateTime":"2016-03-16
>   07:11:33","value":"33.0"},{"dateTime":"2016-03-16
>   07:11:35","value":"35.0"},{"dateTime":"2016-03-16
>   07:11:37","value":"37.0"},{"dateTime":"2016-03-16
>   07:11:39","value":"39.0"}

Currently i am using canvas js chart.

```
 <script src="/public/javascript/canvasjs.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
window.onload = function () {
    var chart = new CanvasJS.Chart("chartContainer",
    {
        title: {
            text: "Date Time Formatting"               
        },
        axisX:{      
            valueFormatString: "hh:mm:ss" ,
            labelAngle: -50
        },
        axisY: {
          valueFormatString: "#,###"
      },

      data: [
      {        
        type: "area",
        color: "rgba(0,75,141,0.7)",
        dataPoints: [

        { x: new Date(07,11,35), y: 0},       
        { x: new Date(07,11,29), y: 20 }, 
        { x: new Date(07,10,53), y: 30 }, 
        { x: new Date(07,10,31), y: 10}

        ]
    }

    ]
});

chart.render();
}
</script>

<div id="chartContainer" style="height: 300px; width: 100%;">
</div>
```

its shows only 12.00:00. Please help how can i show the time on x-axis

Comment: Hi, sorry to reply lately but you have to change the date format. { x: new Date(2015,03,6,07,11,35), y: 0}. Hope that helped you !

Comment: thanks buddy but i already did